# In my Django app, I'm trying to load an image saved in a model but I keep getting "File Not Found"

Tags: django

Here is my relevant settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static","static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "main_app","static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]
```

Relevant model:

```
class posts(models.Model):
    prop_image_main = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

When I configure my template with the following:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ venue.prop_image_main|default_if_none:'#' }}" class="img-responsive" alt="/static/images/portfolio/item-1.jpg" >
```

I get the following error from the command line:

```
"GET /posts/download.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 3360
```

When I add .path or .url to the image in the template, I get the Django error message:

```
The 'prop_image_main' attribute has no file associated with it
```

It seems as if the model is looking in the wrong place for the images (which are saving to the correct directory).
Any idea why?

Comment: You need to use `venue.prop_image_main.url` in the template. More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

Comment: The media directory also needs to be added to the STATICFILES_DIRS list, or the static files app won't serve any files from the MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: I re-configured my STATICFILES_DIRS as updated in my post.  For some reason it still doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by reconfiguring by STATICFILES_DIRS as suggested by @Brandon and adding the .url method.  I then had to delete old entries in my database whose images were saved in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix your image paths with the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`.

Comment: What makes you think you need to do that? The `.url` attribute of the image or file field already contains the relative path to the file.

Comment: I tried both of these options and neither change the output.  This doesn't seem to make sense as they are both present in the documentation.

Comment: Please post your static files settings.

Comment: @Brandon should the media be saved in the same place as other static files?

Comment: @Brandon, I don't think I need to do that, I think @Patrick needs to do that, just because of that "GET /posts/download.jpeg HTTP/1.1", which clearly states that the path misses the `MEDIA_URL` part. I'm not sure about the `.url()` thing, as it, although being clearly the right way to do it, may end up with errors like one Patrick has written about.

Comment: Sorry for hijacking your post.

Comment: Using `.url` is the correct way to access the relative path of an image or file field. There's just nothing serving the files in the /media/ directory.